# Are C# data type sizes fixed or variable?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

When referencing [this](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html) article by Jon Skeet, I see that in C# an `int` would be 4 bytes of memory, and a `struct` like this:

```
struct PairOfInts
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

would be 8 bytes of memory total because:

> The slot of memory is large enough to contain both integers (so it must be 8 bytes).

So if we had this:

```
public int a = 0;
public int b = 2147483647; //the max allowed for an int
```

Would both `a` and `b` still only take up 4 bytes of memory each? Would the same be true of a string? Example:

```
public string c = "";
public string d = "somethingreallyreallylong";
```

Comment: no since there is no `string.Max` ot `string.Min` present. So basically for value type yes but for reference type like `string` no

Comment: in C# `string` is reference type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types in .NET that *absolutely* ignore the "fixed size" rule: `string` and arrays (`int[]`, `SomeType[,,]`, etc). Strings and arrays are allocated with a size appropriate to the declared contents *at construction*; once constructed, each *instance* is fixed size. All other types are fixed size.

Note that `d` is only the **reference** to the string, and the **reference** takes a fixed size. So: `c` and `d` are the same size even when there isn't a string: probably 8 bytes or 4 bytes depending on whethe you're running on 64-bit or 32-bit. The actual `string` *object*, however, will be whatever size it was allocated as when it was created to fit the contents.

Note that "fixed" doesn't mean "known and predictable ahead of time". For many types, the runtime / JIT decides the size based on the execution environment; `IntPtr32`, `Vector<T>`, etc - have sizes that can't be truly known in advance, but *once known*: are fixed for the duration of execution of an application. And even for many `struct`, the padding etc may be determined at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i took a look source code of  `string` and right, it stores `m_firstChar` pointer to memory and `length` of a string and assembles whole string by reading `m_firstChar` `lenght` number of  characters.

Comment: @tchelidze it is more complex than that, actually; `m_firstChar` isn't a pointer - it is a `char`. Essentially, that is where the **first char** goes - everything else is simply sequential after that. The string data is directly in the object, not external via a pointer. Lots of the code will then use `&m_firstChar` to read the value, but this is an *interior* pointer; the data is still 100% inside the object. You can pretty much ignore what the definition looks like for arrays and strings: the runtime completely fakes it :)

Comment: @MarcGravell this is helpful, but would you please elaborate (or just update the answer) more on the 'int' examples? Your answer is explicit for 'string' and arrays, but implicit for 'int'.

Comment: @GreggBursey "All other types are fixed size." (quoted from the above)